# Infinite sum of a function $g(n)=\sum_{d|n \; d\ne n}g(d)$

Tags: summation, arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

Let the function $g:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ be defined as  $$g(n)=\sum_{d|n \; d\ne n}g(d)$$
with $g(1)=1$, how can we evaluate a sum like $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty{g(15^i)\over15^i} \tag1$$
Need we find a closed form for $g(n)$? I have tried to do this with the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), but it has not gotten me anywhere. If we add $g(n)$ to both sides of the definition
$$2g(n)=\sum_{d|n}g(d) $$
I'm unsure if it is acceptable to use the Möbius inversion formula on $2g(n)$, but if it is then
$$g(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\cdot2g\left(\frac nd\right) \Rightarrow g(n)=-2\sum_{d|n \; d\ne n}\mu(d) \,g\left(\frac nd\right)$$
but I don't think this is very useful.
It also doesn't help that $g$ is not multiplicative and I can discern no easy pattern from a table of its values [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qenpR.png). Clearly $g(p)=1$ and the more divisors a number has, the greater the output is. How can I quantify this exactly?

**EDIT**

I have found that $g(n)$ is the same as the number of [ordered factorizations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderedFactorization.html) of $n$, so in $(1)$ 
$$\begin{align} 
g(15^i)&=g(3^i5^i)=2^{2i-1}\sum_{k=0}^i {i\choose k}^22^{-k}\\
\Rightarrow 1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty{g(15^i)\over15^i} &=1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } 2^{2 n-1} 15^{-n} \, _2F_1\left(-n,-n;1;\frac{1}
{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$ Where $F_1$ is a hypergeometric function. Based on some partial sums I think this goes to $\frac{11}{7}$ How can we show this by hand?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, fixed

Comment: $g(p^2)=g(1)+g(p)=2$. $g(pq)=g(1)+g(p)+g(q)=3$. $g(pqr)=13$. Try to find a formula for $g(15^i)$.

Comment: See [OEIS A$002033$](http://oeis.org/A002033) and [OEIS A$074206$](http://oeis.org/A074206).

Comment: @Lucian I noticed that, thanks! I included it in the edit

Answer (score 1):

**Just the start of an idea, really.**

Define $h(1)=1$ and $h(n)=-1$ if $n>1$. Then:

$$(g*h)(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\0&n>1\end{cases}=I(n)$$

where $I(n)$ is the identity under the Dirichlet convolution.

Now, as it turns out $h(n)=2I(n)-\mathbf 1$.

So, $g*(2I-\mathbf 1)=I$ or $g*(I-\mathbf 1/2)=\frac{1}{2}I$.

Let $f_0=I$ and $f_{k+1}(n)=(1*f_k)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} f_k(d)$.

Then $f_k$ is multiplicative, by induction, and we can show that for $k>1$:

$$f_k(p^m)=\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}$$

Let $u = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}f_k$.

Then $u*(I-\mathbf 1/2)=I$, by the usual power series argument, when the series converges, so $(u/2)*(2I-\mathbf 1)=I$, so $u/2=g$

For example:

$$\begin{align}g(p^m)&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}\binom{m+k}{k}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^{m+1}}\\
&=2^{m-1}
\end{align}
$$

Which is the value you see when you just compute by hand.

Using the above formula for $g$, since $f_k$ is multiplicative, $f_k(15^i)=f_k(3^i)f_k(5^i)$, and we have:

$$g(15^i)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{i+k}{k}^2$$

This means you might want to look at the double power series:

$$\sum_{i,k=0}^\infty \binom{i+k}{k}^2 x^iy^k$$

where $x=\frac{1}{15}$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$.

But more generally, that series for $g(n)$ is not symmetric for all $n$.

For example:

$$\sum \frac{g(12^i)}{12^i} = \sum_{i,k=0}^\infty \binom{i+k}{k}\binom{2i+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k12^i}$$

I'm not sure that gets you any closer to a value for the series you want...